# Is it possible to run a Spark Scala script without going inside spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-shell

The only two way I know to run Scala based spark code is to either compile a Scala program into a jar file and run it with spark-submit, or run a Scala script by using :load inside the spark-shell. My question is, it is possible to run a Scala file directly on the command line, without first going inside spark-shell and then issuing :load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use the stdin redirection with `spark-shell`:

```
spark-shell < YourSparkCode.scala
```

This command starts a spark-shell, interprets your `YourSparkCode.scala` line by line and quits at the end.

Another option is to use `-I <file>` option of `spark-shell` command:

```
spark-shell -I YourSparkCode.scala
```

The only difference is that the latter command leaves you inside the shell and you must issue `:quit` command to close the session.

[UDP] 
**Passing parameters**

Since `spark-shell` does not execute your source as an application but just interprets your source file line by line, you cannot pass any parameters directly as application arguments.

Fortunately, there may be a lot of options to approach the same (e.g, externalizing the parameters in another file and read it in the very beginning in your script).

But I personally find the Spark configuration the most clean and convenient way.

Your pass your parameters via `--conf` option:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.myscript.arg1=val1 --conf spark.yourspace.arg2=val2 < YourSparkCode.scala
```

(please note that `spark.` prefix in your property name is mandatory, otherwise Spark will discard your property as invalid)

And read these arguments in your Spark code as below:

```
val arg1: String = spark.conf.get("spark.myscript.arg1")
val arg2: String = spark.conf.get("spark.myscript.arg2")
```

Comment: But is there any way to pass command line arguments like that?

Comment: @MetallicPriest good question. I don't know any really elegant way to parameterize  your code. I see at least 2 options here. First one - to have placeholders in your source file and replace them before you sent the content to the spark-shell. The second one is to pass your parameters as a spark config properties. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via spark-submit.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

You can even put it to bash script either create sbt-task
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html
to run your code.

Comment: Where does it say you can run a Scala file through spark-submit? As far as I know you can only submit a compiled jar file with spark-submit.